# Is there an infinite-dimensional normed vector space in which the set complement of a bounded set may have more than one unbounded component?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, connectedness

Let $n \ge 2$. Using the fact that $\{x \in \mathbf R^n : \lVert x\rVert > R\}$ is connected for each $R > 0$, we can show that if $B \subseteq \mathbf R^n$ is bounded, then $\mathbf R^n \setminus B$ has at most one unbounded connected component. The same obviously then holds for $\mathbf C^n$ for $n \ge 1$, and this fact is used to prove the spectral permanence theorem for Banach algebras. It is however not true in $\mathbf R$, since $[-R, R]^c = (-\infty, -R) \cup (R, \infty)$ has two unbounded connected components.

Does this theorem extend to infinite-dimensional normed vector spaces as well? (over say $\mathbf R$ or $\mathbf C$) Is there a slick description of the spaces in which this theorem does hold?

Comment: It might be interesting/relevant to look up the concept of an “end” of a topological space: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/End_(topology)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The statement for arbitrary (possibly infinite) normed spaces of dimension $\geq 2$ follows immediately from the $2$-dimensional case.  Indeed, suppose $X$ is a normed vector space (over $\mathbb{R}$) of dimension $\geq 2$.  As in the finite dimensional case, it suffices to show that $S=\{x\in X:\|x\|>R\}$ is connected.  Let $x,y\in S$.  If $x$ and $y$ are linearly independent, they span a $2$-dimensional subspace $Y$ of $X$, and then $Y\cap S$ is connected so $x$ and $y$ must be in the same connected component of $S$.  If $x$ and $y$ are linearly dependent, then since $\dim X\geq 2$ we can pick $z\in S$ that is linearly independent from them and then we know $x$ and $y$ must each be in the same connected component as $z$ so they are in the same connected component as each other.  Thus $S$ has only one connected component and is connected.